# References for visualizing numbers in base 10 flats

Tags: reference-request, manipulatives

Base 10 blocks (units, rods, flats and cubes) are a widespread manipulative material for teaching place value.

However, piling rods on top of each other is not very stable, so it is not easy to build one single tower with all pieces that represent a number.

As an alternative, one can use flat pieces for rods, cubes and beyond, exploiting the fact that 10 is a triangular number.

Using this system, 9999 looks like this:[image: 9999 with vertical sum]

I would like to know whether this system has been described before.

Comment: Why is the "900" layer a 10x10x9 cube?

Comment: Well, it is not exactly a cube, but 9 slices of 100 cubes each.

Comment: So, the even powers of ten are all flat squares and the odd powers of ten are all flat, jagged "half-squares"? Interesting idea.

Comment: Yes, this shows all squares. Dienes blocks, instead, show all cubes as cubes.

Comment: The whole point of decimal system is not to "pile rods", but to hide ten needles inside of an egg, then hide ten eggs inside of a duck, then hide ten ducks inside of a rabbit, then hide ten rabbits inside of a chest, buried under an oak tree on an island. Your approach is needlessly complicated to be used as a manipulative for teaching place value.

Comment: @Rusty_Core, I love your image of hiding things inside other things. Although I agree that this system won't help teach place value, this new contributor is having fun thinking about math, and that is way cool.

Comment: Thank you all. But isn't visualization's goal unhiding? The picture organizes 9999 cubes in a way closely related to the positional notation (and vertical sums as well). Maybe I should have added (piled!)
        <pre>9

    +90

  +900

+9000</pre>
to the right of the picture. 
Do you think that base 10 cubes are useful for teaching place value?

Comment: @SueVanHattum Not my image, it is from a [folk tale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koschei).

Comment: I like! I’m curious, what software was used to create the image?

Comment: @EjMak Glad you like it! It is custom software, you may play around here http://mallorcalab.com/arithmoscope/9999.php?n=9999